# PySpark, flattening a nested structure

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, nested, spark-streaming

I have tweets incoming in streaming from Kafka and I've set the following schema for the value part:

```
schema = StructType() \
  .add("data", StructType() \
    .add("created_at", TimestampType())
    .add("text", StringType()))
```

Then I apply the schema to the stream like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.readStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
     .option("subscribe", topics_list) \
     .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
     .load() \
     .select(F.col('key').cast('string'),
             F.from_json(F.col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias('value'),
             F.col('topic'))
```

Receiving the following schema:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
```

I'd like to **flatten the dataframe** to get something like this:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
```

I've looked in other similar questions in StackOverflow but all the answers seemed very complicated so I came up with an idea that made it simpler:

```
df = spark.readStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
     .option("subscribe", topics_list) \
     .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
     .load() \
     .select(F.col('key').cast('string'),
             F.from_json(F.col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias('value'),
             F.col('topic')) \
     .select(F.col('key').cast('string'), F.col('value.data.created_at'), 
             F.col('value.data.text'), F.col('topic'))
```

I just called the .select() method twice, but for that I need to repeat columns and I was wondering if there is another way as simple as possible but not repeating columns as in my solution. I also tried using `F.explode(F.from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias('value'))` but it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use `withColumn` after the select to add new columns based on your initial selection

```py
df \
    .select(
        col("key").cast("string"),
        col("topic"),
        from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("parsed_value"),
    ) \
    .withColumn("created_at", col("parsed_value.created_at"))\
    .withColumn("text", col("parsed_value.text"))\
    .drop("parsed_value")\
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming with a solution, just accessing elements directly inside the .select() statement does it:

```
df = spark.readStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
     .option("subscribe", topics_list) \
     .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
     .load() \
     .select(F.col('key').cast('string'),
            F.from_json(F.col("value").cast("string"), 
              schema)['data']['created_at'].alias('created_at'),
            F.from_json(F.col("value").cast("string"), 
              schema)['data']['text'].alias('text'),
            F.col('topic'))
```